# Palindrome issue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I need  to write a code with a function that has a parameter `str` that evaluates if the word is a palindrome or not, it should return `true`, else ir should return `false`.

**Note:** I need to remove all non-alphanumeric characters.

I wrote the code below but it is giving the opposite of the result expected:

- It is giving false for all the cases.
- Not able to remove the underscore.
- and when use `console.log` below the image I get.

[image: console.log result]

Code:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var exc = /[^\w_]/gi;
  var repStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(exc, "");
  console.log("Replaced string id: " + repStr);
  len = repStr.length -1

  for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== repStr[len] - i) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(palindrome("eye"));
console.log(palindrome("_eye"));
console.log(palindrome("race car"));
console.log(palindrome("not a palindrome"));
console.log(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"));
console.log(palindrome("never odd or even"));
console.log(palindrome("nope"));
console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
console.log(palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym"));
console.log(palindrome("1 eye for of 1 eye."));
console.log(palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0"));
console.log(palindrome("five|\_/|four"));
```

Comment: Underscore is a part of alphanumeric, your regex won't remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your code. 1) the RegExp is not replacing the underscore as `[^\w_]` reads as "everything that is not a word character OR an underscore". Try

```
/[\W_]/g
```

which reads as "one of the following: any character that is not a word character, underscores"

OR

```
/[^0-9a-z]/g
```

which reads as "anything that is not: digits (from 0 to 9), english alphabet letters".

2) For it to work you need to write

```
if(repStr[i] !== repStr[len - i])
```

instead of

```
if(str[i] !== repStr[len] - i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: `/[0-9a-z_]/` also trims the first char, isn't it? 'eye'.replace(/[0-9a-z_]/, '') give ye

Comment: I meant /[^0-9a-z]/g. I'm sorry. I'm dizzy

Comment: Also, that was trimming the first character because it was matching the characters I wanted to keep instead of the other ones and it wasn't global (it didn't have the g flag) so it removed only the first character found

Answer (score 0):

you can simply replace the  two of your lines

```
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++, len--) {
    if (str[i] !== repStr[len]) {
```

check this

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var exc = /[^\w_]/gi;
  var repStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(exc, "");
  console.log("Replaced string id: " + repStr);
  len = repStr.length -1

  for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++, len--) {
    if (str[i] !== repStr[len]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(palindrome("eye"));
console.log(palindrome("_eye"));
console.log(palindrome("race car"));
console.log(palindrome("not a palindrome"));
console.log(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"));
console.log(palindrome("never odd or even"));
console.log(palindrome("nope"));
console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
console.log(palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym"));
console.log(palindrome("1 eye for of 1 eye."));
console.log(palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0"));
console.log(palindrome("five|\_/|four"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    const letters = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ''); // replace any char that is not in the set [a-z] range
    const lowercase = letters.toLowerCase();
    const reversed = lowercase.split('').reverse().join('');
    return lowercase === reversed;
}
```